# Appending text to Date field-Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, rendered, conditional

I have to append a text **PUNS** to a date field (weird customer requirement!) if a custom field "**Material Group**" material_group__c in Object **Order Line** has certain values **A, AB, C.**. Since changing this on UI seems to be the best idea, so I tried as the following....

```
       <apex:column title="Estimated Delivery Date">
                     <apex:facet name="header">EDD</apex:facet>              
                     <apex:outputText value="PUNS-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}" rendered="if(p.material_group__c = 'A', 'AB', 'C')">
                     <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}" rendered="if(NOT((p.material_group__c = 'A', 'AB', 'C'))">
                     <apex:param value="{!p.planned_ship_date__c}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>     
                 </apex:column>
```

Logic is append a text if it belongs to a series of vlaues else display normal date. 
Even though the group is correct, it's not working. I guess I'm lacking correct syntax.

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: when you say A, AB, C do you mean A (or) AB (or) c if so I would use if(OR(p.material_group__c = 'A', p.material_group__c ='AB', p.material_group__c ='C'))

Comment: Yes, I meant  A (or) AB (or) c .I have around 10 such groups. Let me try your method

Comment: Hi @rao. I tried "IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'A', p.material_group__c ='AB', p.material_group__c ='C')) ">. Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the answer

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.gew_material_group__c = 'N2',p.gew_material_group__c = 'P2'),'Week Of-{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}','{0, date, MM/d/yyyy}')}">
```

Posted as an idea from @neff.

Answer (score 1):

When I use the following code :

```
<apex:page standardController="account">          
<apex:outputText value="PUNS-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}">
<apex:param value="{!Account.createddate}"/> 
</apex:outputtext>
</apex:page>
```

I see the output on my vf page as :

> PUNS- 09/22/2014

1) Are you seeing

> PUNS-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}

**IF yes :**

The reason is your param is enclosed only for the 2nd output text val, so you are seeing a basic text

**FIX:**

```
    <apex:outputText value="PUNS-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}" rendered="if(p.material_group__c = 'A', 'AB', 'C')">
   <!-- Display todaysdate-->
    <apex:param value="{!Now}" />
    </apex:ouputText>
```

**IF above is not true ( ie ) NO :**

Check your renedered logic ( I would take the rendered attribute off the second outputtext and check if the date value is rendering fine, if it does you will have to look at why the render is not working)

[image]

Update:

**Your syntax:**

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'N2')),'Week Of-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}','{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}'}">
```

**Corrected syntax:** You closed the IF loop after the OR it has to be {!IF( condition, value1, value2)}

Comment: I see no text. Do I need to have another param ? I removed the rendered part,  text correctly gets appended. I guess the condition statement syntax is incorrect.

Comment: It is rendered that is causing the issue then. Did you try IF(NOT(OR(p.material_group__c = 'A', p.material_group__c ='AB', p.material_group__c ='C'))) " on the rendered logic for the outputtext?

Comment: As far as I know, rendered either displays the value or hides it. I'm unable to display another value if the condition is false. I wanted to achieve this in visualforce. I can do that on controller using flag but better if it was on vf.

Comment: Yes rao I did try the not condition also

Comment: Let me try the if condition inside value

Comment: are you sure you pasted the code right:? I see that you have 2 outputtext but never see where you closed the first outputtext (if you have nested one output text within another you would never see the nested one until the condition evaluates to true), did you trim the code to make it easy for the question?

Comment: Thanks to you, I realized that 1 param is only for 1 outputtext. I removed the second one. I have tried this....  <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'N2')),'Week Of-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}','{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}'}"> Is this even legal?

Comment: Yep it is legal , you do not need the OR( unless you have more material groups to check)  all you are saying is if material group is N2 put in the week of + datevalue of the param (ie planned_ship_date__c) , else just put the date value of planned_ship_date__c.

Comment: It says Sysntax Error. Missing  "}"

Comment: I'm sorry i have many other values to check so here's where I'm at...  <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.material_group__c = 'N2', 'A')),'PUNS-{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}','{0, date, MM'/'d'/'yyyy}'}">  Still shows Sysntax Error. Missing "}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17834/discussion-between-rao-and-mnz).

Comment: This solution worked for me <apex:outputText value="{!IF(OR(p.gew_material_group__c = 'N2',p.gew_material_group__c = 'P2'),'Week Of-{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}','{0, date, MM//d//yyyy}')}"> I will post this as a solution